# How to distort/manipulate dwm live thumbnails in Windows 8, or in any other way get access to window texture?

Tags: windows, winapi, dwm

I have found this: https://github.com/steeve/dwmaxx2

This is how it should work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fpvh16VjrRE

But this seems to not work in Windows 8/8.1, or I'm doing something wrong.  It's loaded, it got valid HWND handle to window to render, but can't get window texture.

Is there any way to get access to window texture, and be able to map it to some 3d object like cube?

Answer (score 5):

DWM uses private DXGI COM interface which is undocumented. While you wanna get access windows texture, it's possible to hook private DXGI COM.

for Win7:

```
/* interface IDXGIFactoryDWM */
static const GUID IID_IDXGIFactoryDWM = {0x713F394E,0x92CA,0x47E7
                            ,{0xAB,0x81,0x11,0x59,0xC2,0x79,0x1E,0x54}};
struct IDXGIFactoryDWM: public IUnknown
{
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateSwapChain(IUnknown *pDevice,
                      DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC *pDesc, IDXGIOutput *pOutput, 
                      IDXGISwapChainDWM **ppSwapChain) = 0;
};

/* interface IDXGISwapChainDWM */
static const GUID IID_IDXGISwapChainDWM = {0xF69F223B,0x45D3,0x4AA0,
                                {0x98,0xC8,0xC4,0x0C,0x2B,0x23,0x10,0x29}};

struct IDXGISwapChainDWM: public IDXGIDeviceSubObject
{
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Present(UINT SyncInterval, UINT Flags) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetBuffer(UINT Buffer, REFIID riid, void **ppSurface) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetDesc(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC *pDesc) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ResizeBuffers(UINT BufferCount, UINT Width, UINT Height, DXGI_FORMAT NewFormat, UINT SwapChainFlags) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ResizeTarget(const DXGI_MODE_DESC *pNewTargetParameters) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetContainingOutput(IDXGIOutput **ppOutput) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetFrameStatistics(DXGI_FRAME_STATISTICS *pStats) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetLastPresentCount(UINT *pLastPresentCount) = 0;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetFullscreenState(BOOL Fullscreen, IDXGIOutput *pTarget) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetFullscreenState(BOOL *pFullscreen, IDXGIOutput **ppTarget) = 0;
};
```

for Win8:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("{1ddd77aa-9a4a-4cc8-9e55-98c196bafc8f}"))
IDXGIFactoryDWM8 : public IUnknown
{
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateSwapChainDWM(
    /* [annotation][in] */ 
    _In_ IUnknown *pDevice, 
    /* [annotation][in] */ 
    _In_ DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 *pSwapChainDesc1, 
    /* [annotation][in] */ 
    _In_ DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FULLSCREEN_DESC *pSwapChainFullScreenDesc1, 
    /* [annotation][in] */ 
    _In_ IDXGIOutput * pOutput, 
    /* [annotation][out] */ 
    _Out_ IDXGISwapChainDWM8 ** ppSwapChainDWM1
    ) = 0;

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateSwapChainDDA(
    /* [annotation][in] */ 
    _In_ IUnknown *pDevice, 
    /* [annotation][in] */ 
    _In_ DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 *pSwapChainDesc1, 
    /* [annotation][in] */ 
    _In_ IDXGIOutput * pOutput, 
    /* [annotation][out] */ 
    _Out_ IDXGISwapChainDWM8 ** ppSwapChainDWM8
    ) = 0;
}
```